# Which one is accurate? Ma collège or mon collège

Tags: grammaire, articles

Mon collège or mon collège
Which one is accurate enough?

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about the secondary school, the word ***collège*** is masculine so it is not about being more or less accurate, ***mon collège*** is right, *<s>**ma**</s> **collège*** is wrong.

If you misspelled ***collègue***, then both ***mon** collègue* and ***ma** collègue* are grammatically correct. The possessive adjective to use will depend on the gender of that colleague of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Mon collège would be more accurate.